# How to get resnet50 model to predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am following a tutorial to create a deep learning model that takes ct scan images and detects from the ct scan whether its covid or not using resnet50

The model summary :

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 resnet50 (Functional)       (None, 2048)              23587712  
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 2048)              0         
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 2048)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 2)                 4098      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 23,591,810
Trainable params: 1,059,842
Non-trainable params: 22,531,968
```

when I try to predict using this :

```
pred=model.predict(img)
pr_cl=np.argmax(pred,axis=1)
```

i get output :

> array([0], dtype=int64)

the output remains same for both covid and non-covid images

There are 2 classes (COVID and non-COVID) :
Found 1986 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 495 images belonging to 2 classes.

How do i get the proper prediction from model showing whether its covid or not ?

Full Code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, BatchNormalization
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
base_dir = r'\filepath for dataset'
img_h,img_w= (164,164)
batch_size=32
epochs=10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen= ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,validation_split=0.2)
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19, preprocess_input
#from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten,Dense,Dropout,BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import PReLU
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau

base_model= ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                                       input_tensor=None, input_shape=(img_h,img_w,3), pooling='avg')
 
for layer in base_model.layers[:-7]:
    layer.trainable=False

 
model=Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))


model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

for layer in base_model.layers:
    print(layer,"-->",layer.trainable)

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam,SGD,Adagrad,Adadelta,RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau


reduce_learning_rate = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss',
                                         factor=0.1,
                                         patience=3,
                                         cooldown=2,
                                         min_lr=1e-10,
                                         verbose=1)

checkpoint =tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath="reswtk.h5", 
                            monitor='val_accuracy',
                            verbose=1,
                            save_best_only=True, 
                            save_weights_only=False, 
                            mode='auto',
                            save_freq='epoch')


import time
class TimeHistory(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.times = []

    def on_epoch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.epoch_time_start = time.time()

    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.times.append(time.time() - self.epoch_time_start)

time_callback = TimeHistory()

callbacks = [reduce_learning_rate, checkpoint, time_callback]
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile( loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer= optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        base_dir,  # This is the source directory for training images
        target_size=(img_h, img_w),  
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='training',
        #color_mode="rgb",
        shuffle=True)


validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
         base_dir,     
        target_size=(img_h, img_w),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        #color_mode="rgb",
        subset='validation',
        shuffle=False)

history = model.fit(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples//batch_size, 
      epochs=epochs,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=validation_generator.samples//batch_size,  
      callbacks=callbacks,
      verbose=1)

model.evaluate(validation_generator,verbose=1)
accu= history.history['val_accuracy']
print(max(accu),"at epoch number-",accu.index(max(accu))+1)

img = cv2.imread("\filepath for png file") 
image_resized= cv2.resize(img, (img_h,img_w))
cv2.imshow('CT scan', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
img=np.expand_dims(image_resized,axis=0)
img.shape

pred=model.predict(img)
pr_cl=np.argmax(pred,axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you show what is `pred` equal to? `print(pred)`

Comment: @ArthurHakobyan pred is coming as : array([[1.0000000e+00, 1.3036212e-12]], dtype=float32)

Comment: @ArthurHakobyan print(pred) is [[1.0000000e+00 3.6550784e-08]]

Comment: for all images pred[0] is 1 ?

Comment: please show labels of train

Comment: @ArthurHakobyan classes are COVID and non-COVID and yes pred[0] is coming same for all images. and how do i show labels on train ?

Comment: if class is COVID ,label is 1 or [0,1], non-COVID label is 0 or [1,0]?

Comment: @ArthurHakobyan if class is covid label is 0 and for non-COVID label is 1

Comment: @ArthurHakobyan its working correctly. i found that the issue was with the dataset as a lot of the images were the same which is why even in different classes it was giving the same pred value. Thanks !